# Linux bash grouping

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this file:

```
count,name
1,B1
1,B1
1,B3
1,B3
1,B2
1,B2
1,B2
```

and I routinely have to get counters on the total per group. The first number is always one. The only important thing is the group. I wrote a java program to do it for me. The output would be

```
B1: 2
B2: 3
B3: 2
```

The format is not important, just the counters per group name.

I was wondering, can this be done in bash? awk? sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is very simple to solve with `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort file | uniq -c
  2 1,B1
  3 1,B2
  2 1,B3
```

Then, if you need the proper formatting, you may use `cut` to strip the first column, and `awk` to print the result:

```
$ cut -d ',' -f 2 file | sort | uniq -c | awk '{printf "%s: %d\n", $2, $1}'
  B1: 2
  B2: 3
  B3: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk, I would write

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {n[$2]++} END {OFS=":";for (x in n) print x, n[x]}' file
```

assuming you actually have a header line in the file.